# How to trim in v-if vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

A few days, i try to trim the response value in a vue condition.

I need this, when the value is null or empty apply the condition.

```
<li v-if="item[0].otrodl4.trim() == ''" class="progress-step">
```

But I got the error

*vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null"*

The problem is that some values bring only whitespace and no more, that should be considered null or empty.

E.G.

[image]

I tried it with filters but I get the same error.

Thanks for read.

Greetings.

Comment: There are so many other ways to check for null or empty. Why this method over any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a TypeError where the variable you are trying to manipulate is not what it is thought to be by the developer.

Always happen to a language without proper typing.

Therefore, you can do an optional chaining and check the variable is what it is supposed to be first.

ES2020 has allowed us to use optional chaining to type check.

For example,

```
v-if="!!item?.[0]?.otrodl4?.trim && item?.[0]?.otrodl4?.trim() == ''"
```

!! is a type conversion to falsy values like null or undefined or empty string to become false.

It makes sure that `otrodl4` has a property method trim before calling the method and therefore won't cause TypeError anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
!item || !item[0] || !item[0].otrodl4 || item[0].otrodl4.trim() == ''
```

Basically, you have to check that `item` is defined and not null. And that the first element of that array exists AND that this element has `otrodl4` property.

Comment: Don't work.I try some cases but i get the same error or dont work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`item[0] && item[0].otrodl4.trim() == ''`

So, the only time it checks if `item[0].otrodl4.trim() == ''` is if there's a value in the `0` index position of the item array.

It's known as a `short-circuit` conditional and you can read all about it [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-conditionals-bbc13ac3e9eb).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with trim() and it is working fine. please try if this can be help to you.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<!--if only space in text it will display "hello space" else no dsplay.  -->
<p v-if="text.trim()==''">hello whitespace {{ text | trim }}</p>

</div> 
<script>
new Vue({

el: '#app',
  
  data: function() {
    return {
        text: ' '    // added only a space
    }
  }
  
 

});
</script> 
         
</body>
</html>
```